# how to exclude properties of super class when generating open API spec using swagger in java

Tags: java, rest, configuration, swagger

We have a class which is inherited from third party library class.
While generating open API spec using swagger, 
in schema all the properties of the third party class are also getting displayed along with our class properties.

Is there any way we can exclude all the properties from the third party library class in order to display only our class properties generated schema?

Comment: Sadly, it is a missing feature from the swagger. Another guy has the same issue as you. (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/730). There is an option to hide property in the ApiModelProperty annotation but it means you also have to modify to the base class.

Comment: To be entirely correct with this, you shouldn't simply hide the properties from swagger. Because while it will not be in docs, it still would be discoverable and usable. It unnecessarily opens your system to possible exploitation - someone could still send you the hidden property, and your app would still deserialize it.

Comment: There are parameters like createdTime, updatedTime that the frontend should not care for at all. Its important to have the need to hide superclass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Include @ApiIgnore over the specific API to hide from Swagger Documentation.

Include @JsonIgnore over the specific property variable which needs to hide from Swagger Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for that
I added the un-needed properties into the child class and then used the     `@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)` on them

```
public class ExternalClass {
    public String externalId;
    ...
}

public class OwnClass extends ExternalClass {

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
    public String externalId;
    ...
    //our properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `ExternalClass` like this

```
@Schema(subTypes = { 
    Subclass1.class, Subclass2.class, ...
        })
public class OwnClass extends ExternalClass {
...
```

where `Subclass1.class, Subclass2.class, ...` extend from `OwnClass`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the generated OpenAPI definition to understand which annotation to use. In my case, the superclass was included in the `allOf` property.

It was looking something like that:

```
    User:
      description: User
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/AbstractResource_User_'
      - required:
        - name
        type: object
        properties:
           ...
```

To exclude it I had to **explicitly** add the `@Schema(allOf = {})` annotation to the top of my `User` class definition:

```
@Schema(allOf = {})
public class User extends AbstractResource<User> {
    ...
}
```

This excluded the `AbstractResource` class from the OpenAPI schema.

Comment: allOf = {} is the default value in schema annotation, shouldn't help

Comment: @khodayarJ - the default gets overridden. That's why you need to explicitly add it again. It does nothing with the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Class type in **ignoredParameterTypes** method to exclude the classes you don’t want to include.

```
  @Configuration
  public class SpringFoxConfig {                                    

    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
        .select()                                  
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
        .build()
        .ignoredParameterTypes(ExcludeClass.class);                                           
    }
}
```